# How does a six-axis force/torque sensor work?

Tags: sensors, force-sensor

I would really like a six-axis force/torque sensor for my robot, but I just can't afford one. I was thinking about making one of my own.

I have experience using strain gauges, but I can't work out how to arrange them so as to create a six-axis force/torque sensor.

- Is this something I could feasibly make myself?
- How do they work? What is the theory behind them?

I'm curious to know how they work, even if it's not feasible to make one myself.

---

Added:

Just to be clear, I'm talking about *force / torque* sensors, like this [ATI Nano 17](http://www.ati-ia.com/products/ft/ft_models.aspx?id=Nano17):

[image: ATI Nano]

I am not talking about accelerometers or gyros, or MEMS IMUs.

Comment: Are you asking about a six axis force sensor for use as an intertial measurement unit (accelerometer & gyroscope)? Or something else?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think its entirely impossible to build something like this, especially if you already have some experience with strain gauges. I think the most common way is to arrange the sensor in a [Stewart Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_platform). There are a lot of articles on this, e.g. "Closed-form force sensing of a 6-axis force transducer based on the Stewart platform".

A similar Sensor from Schunk [FT Nano](http://www.schunk.com/schunk_files/attachments/FT-Nano_017_EN.pdf) says in the datasheet:

> Monolithic element with three measuring phases with an angle of 120°.
>   Each phase has two semiconductor strain measuring bridges which record
>   deformation in the micrometer range.

Comment: Interesting, but is this actually what's inside something like the ATI Nano 17 ?